# UI Router dynamic <title> tag

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, title

I'm adding a title to every state in the ui-router like that:

```
.state('projects', {
    url: '/',
    templateUrl: 'projects/projects.html',
    ncyBreadcrumb: {
        label: 'Projects'
    },
    data : {title: 'Projects'}
})
```

And then the title attribute takes that data:

```
<title ng-bind="$state.current.data.title"></title>
```

How can I take data from the state parameters and add it to the title in the above example? I tried the following with no luck:

```
.state('project', {
    abstract: true,
    url: '/projects/:projId',
    resolve:{
        projId: ['$stateParams', function($stateParams){
            return $stateParams.projId;
        }]
    },
    controller: 'projectCtrl',
    templateUrl: 'project/project.html',
    ncyBreadcrumb: {
        label: 'Project',
        parent: 'projects'
    },
    data : {title: '{{state}}'}
})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have to use **app.run()** in your app.js file and assign your title in **$rootScope.title** . you can follow this code

```
app.run(function($rootScope){
    $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function(event, toState, toParams, fromState){

        $rootScope.title=toState.data.title;
    });
});
```

after this then bind the variable in your html like this

```
<title ng-bind="title"></title>
```

I think it will helpful

Comment: you didn't explain how can you set dynamic title for `toState.data.title`

Comment: here is the route
`.state('projects', {
    url: '/',
    templateUrl: 'projects/projects.html',
    ncyBreadcrumb: {
        label: 'Projects'
    },
    data : {title: 'Projects'}
})`

so from the route I just get title from `data.title`

Comment: yes its hard coded not dynamic, he asked how to bind this data to the **<tittle>**. so I just show how to do it

Comment: I think I'm confused because of this `{{state}}` which indicated dynamic for me

Comment: Actually he did not explain the problem properly :D

Answer (score 0):

There is [a working example](http://plnkr.co/edit/sg3hqiKQf2Rj8qoylVoN?p=preview)

I would say, you are almost there. The title could look like this:

```
<title>{{$state.current.data.title}} {{$stateParams.ID}}</title>
```

Let's have these two states:

```
  .state('parent', {
      url: "/parent",
      templateUrl: 'tpl.html',
      data : { title: 'Title for PARENT' },
  })
  .state('parent.child', { 
      url: "/child/:ID",
      templateUrl: 'tpl.html',
      controller: 'ChildCtrl',
      data : { title: 'Title for CHILD' },
  })
  ;
```

And call them like this:

```
<a ui-sref="parent">
<a ui-sref="parent.child({ID:1})">
<a ui-sref="parent.child({ID:2})">
```

And with this hook:

```
.run(['$rootScope', '$state', '$stateParams',
  function ($rootScope, $state, $stateParams) {
    $rootScope.$state = $state;
    $rootScope.$stateParams = $stateParams;
}])
```

So, the point is, that in a `$rootScope` we can access both, **`$state.current`** and **`$stateParams`**

Check it [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/sg3hqiKQf2Rj8qoylVoN?p=preview) *(NOTE, to see plunker in separated window, click the right -top corner blue icon - new window will change the title as well)*

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest you to use params option instead of using `data` option, because params can be optional and you can set it dynamically by passing parameter inside your `$state.go` or `ui-sref` directive.

**Code**

```
.state('projects', {
    url: '/',
    templateUrl: 'projects/projects.html',
    ncyBreadcrumb: {
        label: 'Projects'
    },
    params: {
        title: { value: null }
    }
});
```

**From Controller**

```
$state.go('projects', {title: 'Page1'}); //you can change title while calling state
```

**From HTML**

```
ui-sref="projects({title: 'Something Else'})"
```